# Android - Retrofit : java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to call an API on my personal Backend server and I get this SSL error in response.

How can I ask Retrofit to ignore SSL errors ?

Thanks,

```
2019-07-17 15:43:33.385 31394-31394/com.test E/com.test.site.ui.SiteFragment: getSitesList() - onFailure() Could not load sites list: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:229)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:351)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:310)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:178)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
```

App.kt:

```
package com.test

import android.app.Application
import com.test.site.service.SiteService
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


class App : Application() {

    companion object {

        lateinit var instance: App

        // Create interceptor to get HTTP logs
        private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor())
            .build();

        // Create retrofit instance for whole application
        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(httpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://api.mydomain.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        // Create siteService
        val siteService: SiteService = retrofit.create(SiteService::class.java)

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }


}
```

Comment: "How can I ask Retrofit to ignore SSL errors ?" -- you don't, unless you want your app to be banned from the Play Store. What is unusual about your Web server's setup that is causing Android to not recognize the source of your SSL certificate?

Comment: I have the "pem" certificate of my backend server. How can I integrate this certificate with retrofit ?

Answer (score -1):

> I have the "pem" certificate of my backend server. How can I integrate this certificate with retrofit ?

You already have a custom `OkHttpClient`. Add logic to it to teach it [about your custom SSL certificate](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/#customizing-trusted-certificates). Then, since Retrofit is using your `OkHttpClient`, Retrofit will know about that SSL certificate and should work with your server.

Or, switch your server to use an SSL certificate from a recognized root authority (e.g., Let's Encrypt).